# Escaping special characters in filepaths using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, escaping, filepath

I'm storing filenames and filepaths in MySQL.  Retrieving them from the database using `LIKE` expressions requires that I escape all allowed filename chars that collide with MySQL special chars.  I'm happy to simply use Python's `string.replace()` method, but was wondering if there was a more standard or built-in method of sanitizing filepaths with SQLAlchemy or dealing with filepaths in MySQL in general.

I need the solution to be OS-agnostic and established.  It does not need to be implemented in SA.  I'll accept any procedure for encoding that works; failing that, I need a list of all chars that need to be escaped and a smart choice of an escape char.

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy do sanitize for you if you will use regular queries. Maybe the problem that you use like clause. Like require addition escape for such symbols: _%. Thus you will need replace methods if you want to quote like expression.

Comment: The fact that i use `.like()` is not the problem, it is the main requirement.  Do I need only escape `%` and `_`?  How to handle literal quotes, brackets, and backslashes?

Comment: You need to escape only 3 characters, _,%,/. _ and % are wildcards, / - escape symbol. Other part of the query will be sanitized automatically

Answer (score -3):

Why do you need to escape the file paths? As far as you are not manually writing select / insert queries, SQLAlchemy will take care of the escaping when it generates the query internally.

The file paths can be inserted as they are into the database.

Comment: I am using the `.like()` SA method to select filepaths. Which (as I understand) uses `%` and `_` (are there others?) as wildcards. Both are also valid filname chrs. It would certainly be strange if SA could read my mind and know when I was using `_` as a search wildcard vs. a literal char in a filename and "take care" of it for me! :)

Comment: @Toofan: Paul is right: SQLAlchemy won't do this for `.like()` and consorts (`.contains()`, `.startswith()` etc...). It does provide an `escape` argument for these methods, but you have to escape the string yourself, and provide the used escape character.

Answer (score -3):

As I know there isn’t what you are looking for in SQLAlchemy. Just go `basestring.replace()` method by yourself.

Comment: Yes.  I know.  I say that in my question.  What should I replace to?  Isn't '*' and '\' valid linux filename chars?  Isn't there some standard encoding I should use?  I've considered doing an url-encode but with an escaped or double-% instead of a %, but it gets messy quickly.  I'm looking for an esablished solution.

Answer (score -4):

You don't need do anything SQLAlchemy will do it for you.

Comment: read the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713715/escaping-special-characters-using-sqlalchemy/6720094#6720094

Comment: then you must write your escape function by yourself: path.replace('%','\\%').replace('_','\\_')

Comment: Or you can use sql like so: select * from table where a like 'andre*%' escape '*';

Comment: For this in sqlAlchemy there is column operator like with definition:  like(other, escape=None) http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/expression_api.html?highlight=like#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.like

Comment: Yes, and now you see my issue with filepaths.  The backslash is a chr in every windows filepath.  Finding an escape char that is not a valid char in some file-system is an issue.  Do I need to escape `'` and `"` and various brackets?  Like my question states, I am happy to do the .replace() you suggest, but I was looking for a best-practice, common, or well-thought-out solution for filepaths in mysql in general.

Comment: You don't need to escape quotes SA will escape the by it self, escape parametr in like operator needed to escape chars that are special chars for like expression.

Comment: If you need to use % or _ or * at the same time as a char and as an special char, then you must wrote escpae function by yourself

Comment: The main problem that you have is that you save yor path not escaped, and then when you try to use like, you having trouble like this.